# RUM (Real User Monitoring) User-perceived load times and location

Tags: javascript, performance, graphite, page-load-time, statsd

I wish to monitor user-perceived page load times on my website based on the users approximate geographical location as well as other info such as browser versions etc. This can all be gathered via JavaScript on the pages. My issue however is what is the best option for sending, storing and then presenting the data that I am monitoring? I have looked at graphite and statsd but I am unsure if these would work as I need to show correlations between user location and load times for various pages e.g. Login, Create new order, etc

Answer (score 3):

If you want to roll your own use boomerang.js to collect and log the data to a web server.

In the simplest case you can they just parse the HTTP logs for the data, if you want to get more sophisticated look at https://github.com/nature/boomcatch

Answer (score 0):

Graphite and statsd are what you need. You just need to be thoughtful about how you parse that information out of the logs and send it to statsd.  You send statsd a stat_name and stat_value. The stat_name will be the key to organizing your data by user location, browser type, etc. It is a namespace delimited by '.' characters. So if you parse your log correctly you could call the stat :

stat.server1.client_location.browser_type.load_time

It will then appear in the graphite UI under a directory structure corresponding to the namespace, so you could roll up data by server,location or browser type if you wanted to.

EDIT: After rereading your question, it is kind of difficult to plot location against load time in Graphite. It is more focused on having time along the x-axis. However, it can be done with some work in R: https://danslimmon.wordpress.com/2013/04/05/parameterizing-metrics-by-time-through-graphite-abuse/

Comment: Given that statsd can handle the parameters that I want (stat.server1.client_location.browser_type.load_time) and from the link you gave Graphite does look configurable to present what I want. Can statsd handle different values being sent in each time i.e. stat.value1.value2 and then stat.value1.value2,value3?  As for getting the data to Statsd in theory what I have considered is using javascript to get perceived load times using the navigation.timing api and then get the other information too.  This will then be sent via UDP to a node.js server which will send it to statsd.

Comment: Yea you can use javascript and Navigation Timing, or you can use boomerang.js, which is a javascript library that uses the Navigation Timing API if it is enabled on the clients browser.  It gets the perceived load times, among other things if you desire from your users (RUM). There are also instructions to get a asynchronous non-blocking version running on your web pages. 
https://github.com/lognormal/boomerang/
I am not sure if I understand this question about "different values being sent in". Currently I have statsd processing over 100 unique metrics.

Answer (score 0):

You can tryout the service https://www.atatus.com/ which provides Real user monitoring, Ajax Monitoring, Transaction Monitoring and JavaScript Error tracking for web apps and hybrid apps.

PS: Web developer at Atatus